# Javascript event on click on dropdown arrow

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

Is there an event which fires or can I write a custom event to be fired when user selects dropdown anchor?

[image]

I need to remove `Top` from the dwopdown list I get from the web service. Once the user selects on any item it should be back to `Top International` again.

[image]

Comment: just use the `click` event for the whole select - there's no a specific event for the arrow

Comment: @F.Calderan I needed to know the same, Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by *Once the user selects on any item it should be back to `Top International` again*? Do you just want the *value* to include `Top`? If so, just remove `Top` from the displayed value, i.e. you end up with something like `<option value="Top International">International</option>`... no need for event handling here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var isselect = false;

$("#dropdown").click(function() {
    if(!isselect)
    {
       //dropdown arrow is clicked.
    }
    else
    { 
       //dropdown item is selected
    }
});
$("#dropdown").change(function() {
    isselect = true;
    setTimeout(clearIsselect,10);
});
function clearIsselect() {
    isselect = false;
}
```